# Python: Pandas: Save Index of DataFrames in textfile as columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of DataFrames df_list. I want to write a tab delimited textfile: The first row is the index of the list. Each column is then the values in the DataFrame index. The index.values have not the same lenght.

```
0   1   2   3
i   i   i   i
n   n   n   .
d   d   .   .
e   .   .   .
x   .   .
.   .   
v
a
l
u
e
s
```

I tried:

```
arrays = []
    for i in range(len(df_list)):
        arrays.append(df_list[i].index.values)
np.savetxt('clusters.txt', np.transpose(arrays))
```

But I get: `TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')`

When I use (piRSquared´s answer):

```
df_master = pd.DataFrame({i: df.index.to_series() for i, df in enumerate(df_list)})
sorted_cols = df_master.notnull().sum().sort_values()[::-1].index
df_master[sorted_cols].to_csv('clusters.txt', sep='\t', index=None, float_format='%0.0f')
```

I get for example:

```
  7     21

  D0EX67    



  E1MTY0    
  P00350    
        P00363
  P00370    


        P00452
        P00490
```

Is there a way to get rid of the empty cells?

Comment: What sort of values are your indices?

Comment: Strings:
df_list[0].index.values
Out[23]: 
array(['P00892', 'Q2A0K9', 'P33218', 'P0AA63', 'P75954', 'P07023',
       'P0ACL9', 'P00888', 'P0AE85', 'P24177', 'P0AEN4'], dtype=object)

Answer (score 2):

```
df_list = [pd.DataFrame(range(i)) for i in range(10, 15)]

df_master = pd.DataFrame({i: df.index.to_series() for i, df in enumerate(df_list)})
sorted_cols = df_master.notnull().sum().sort_values()[::-1].index

print df_master[sorted_cols].to_csv(sep='\t', index=None, float_format='%0.0f')
```

[image]

To save to a file:

```
df_master.to_csv('mytextfile.txt', sep='\t')
```

Comment: I don´t want the index and also there are empty cells in the columns (with my df_list)

Comment: @Benni you're going to have to do a better job explaining what it is you want the file to look like.  I don't know what "no empty cells" means.  If they are uneven length... I have an idea.

Comment: The values are unique. In the textfile, they are in the same row as the index (which is the same value). So if there is only one value in the df_list[i].index.value it gets printed in the row, where the index is. All other rows are empty in this column